# Proving $(V\oplus W)^*\cong V^*\oplus W^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$. Prove that
>   $$(V\oplus W)^*\cong V^*\oplus W^*$$
>   by constructing an explicit isomorphism.

I'm pretty sure I know the isomorphism, but I'm struggling to show that it is in fact a bijection. Here's what I have so far:

Note that
$$(V\oplus W)^*=\{\varphi|\varphi:V\oplus W\rightarrow\mathbb{F}, \varphi \mbox{ is linear}\},$$
$$V^*\oplus W^*=\{(\psi,\theta)|\psi:V\rightarrow\mathbb{F},\theta:W\rightarrow\mathbb{F},\psi,\theta \mbox{ are linear}\}.$$
Let $\psi\in V^*$ and $\theta\in W^*$ and define
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}:V\oplus W\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$$
by
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}(v,w)=\psi(v)+\theta(w).$$
We will show that $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ defines an isomorphism from $V^*\oplus W^*$ to $(V\oplus W)^*$. First, observe that since $\psi,\theta$ are linear by definition, it follows that
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}(c_1(v_1+v_2),c_2(w_1+w_2))=c_1\psi(v_1)+c_1\psi(v_2)+c_2\theta(w_1)+c_2\theta(w_2)$$
for all $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{F}$, $v_1,v_2\in V$, and $w_1,w_2\in W$. Hence, $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is linear.

---

I think the best way to show injectivity is to show that $\ker(L_{(\psi,\theta)})$ is trivial, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to do so. I think surjectivity is shown by just checking the definition, but again this isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Both properties are similar to check: For injectivity assume $L_{(\psi_1,\theta_1)}=L_{(\psi_2,\theta_2)}$ and look at what happens when you fix $w=0$ and let $v$ vary, and viceversa. For surjectivity, given $\varphi$ define $\psi(v)= \varphi(v+0)$ and similarly for $\theta$.

Comment: It might have been easier to think of these ideas if instead you had to prove $(V\times W)^* \cong V^*\oplus W^*$, which is probably the right way of thinking about it since the "dual" of the direct sum is the direct product. Of course in our case both operations coincide but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jose27's comment and my initial attempt:

Note that
$$(V\oplus W)^*=\{\varphi|\varphi:V\oplus W\rightarrow\mathbb{F}, \varphi \mbox{ is linear}\},$$
$$V^*\oplus W^*=\{(\psi,\theta)|\psi:V\rightarrow\mathbb{F},\theta:W\rightarrow\mathbb{F},\psi,\theta \mbox{ are linear}\}.$$
Let $\psi\in V^*$ and $\theta\in W^*$ and define
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}:V\oplus W\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$$
by
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}(v,w)=\psi(v)+\theta(w).$$
We will show that $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ defines an isomorphism from $V^*\oplus W^*$ to $(V\oplus W)^*$ by showing that $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is a linear bijection. First, observe that since $\psi,\theta$ are linear by definition, it follows that
$$L_{(\psi,\theta)}(c_1(v_1+v_2),c_2(w_1+w_2))=c_1\psi(v_1)+c_1\psi(v_2)+c_2\theta(w_1)+c_2\theta(w_2)$$
for all $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{F}$, $v_1,v_2\in V$, and $w_1,w_2\in W$. Hence, $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is linear. To see that $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is injective, suppose
$$L_{(\psi_1,\theta_1)}(v,w)=L_{(\psi_2,\theta_2)}(v,w)$$
for some $\psi_1,\psi_2\in V^*$ and $\theta_1,\theta_2\in W^*$, and all $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. Then
\begin{align*}
    L_{(\psi_1,\theta_1)}(0,w)&=L_{(\psi_2,\theta_2)}(0,w)\\
    \Rightarrow\psi_1(0)+\theta_1(w)&=\psi_2(0)+\theta_2(w)\\
    \Rightarrow\theta_1(w)&=\theta_2(w)
\end{align*}
for all $w\in W$. Hence $\theta_1=\theta_2$. It is similarly shown that $\psi_1=\psi_2$. Hence $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is injective. To see that $L_{(\psi,\theta)}$ is surjective, given $\varphi\in(V\oplus W)^*$, define
$$\psi(v):=\varphi(v+0), ~~ \theta(w):=\varphi(0+w),$$
for each $v\in V$, and $w\in W$. It is clear that $\psi$ and $\theta$ are linear, hence, $\psi\in V^*$, $\theta\in W^*$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    L_{(\psi,\theta)}(v,w)&=\psi(v)+\theta(w)\\
    &=\varphi(v+0)+\varphi(0+w)\\
    &=\varphi(v+w)
\end{align*}
The desired result follows.